# JTextArea on Nimbus being inconsistent across different machines

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea, nimbus

I have a class extending `JPanel` that I want to embed into a `JFrame`. The L&F is set to Nimbus, and the layout I'm using for the panel is a `GridBagLayout`.

---

When I gave the JAR to a friend, a `JTextArea` I intend to use as a log console started acting up and wouldn't stay the size I set it to.

`textAreaLog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(295, 48));`

I'm using WinXP SP2, and my friend's using Win7 64-bit. Here's a picture of how it looks on my PC (left) and his PC (right):

[Image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17850283/parser_comparison.png)

Obviously I intended it to be the way I have it on my machine.

---

Here's the relevant code (almost the whole class used for the panel):

```
package com.sassilization.mapfix.gui;

// Imports the package with the inner-workings of the application
import com.sassilization.mapfix.MapFixGenerator;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LogPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8324191587703173738L;

    /*
    * Constructor
    */
    public LogPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 70));
        // Creates a default Nimbus border
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder((String) null));
        setOpaque(false);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        // Calls the method which initializes all the components
        initComponents();
    }

    /*
    * Component declarations
    */
    private JButton buttonFgd;
    private JButton buttonHelp;
    private JButton buttonLogCopy;
    private JButton buttonLogDown;
    private JButton buttonLogUp;
    private JTextArea textAreaLog;
    private JToggleButton toggleButtonAppend;

    /*
    * Initializes and adds all the components to the panel
    */
    private void initComponents() {
        // The constraints used to lay out the components in a GBL
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        // The brick button
        toggleButtonAppend = new JToggleButton(appendIcons[0]);
        toggleButtonAppend.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        toggleButtonAppend.setToolTipText("Turn append mode on");
        toggleButtonAppend.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                buttonAppendItemStateChanged(event);
            }
        });
        add(toggleButtonAppend, gbc);

        // The question mark button
        buttonHelp = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/help.png")));
        buttonHelp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        buttonHelp.setToolTipText("Open help");
        buttonHelp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                // buttonHelpActionPerformed(event);
            }
        });
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(buttonHelp, gbc);

        // The white page button
        buttonFgd = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/page_white_put.png")));
        buttonFgd.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        buttonFgd.setToolTipText("Extract FGD file");
        buttonFgd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                // buttonFgdActionPerformed(event);
            }
        });
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        add(buttonFgd, gbc);

        // The problematic JTextArea
        textAreaLog = new JTextArea();
        textAreaLog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(295, 48));
        textAreaLog.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 12, 0, 0,
                new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/border.png"))));
        textAreaLog.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        textAreaLog.setForeground(new Color(171, 193, 207));
        textAreaLog.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 9));
        textAreaLog.setLineWrap(true);
        textAreaLog.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textAreaLog.setEditable(false);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        add(textAreaLog, gbc);

        // The up arrow button
        buttonLogUp = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/bullet_arrow_up.png")));
        buttonLogUp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        buttonLogUp.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        buttonLogUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                // buttonLogUpActionPerformed(event);
            }
        });
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        add(buttonLogUp, gbc);

        // The floppy disk button
        buttonLogCopy = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/bullet_disk.png")));
        buttonLogCopy.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        buttonLogCopy.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        buttonLogCopy.setToolTipText("Copy log to clipboard");
        buttonLogCopy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                // buttonLogCopyActionPerformed(event);
            }
        });
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(buttonLogCopy, gbc);

        // The down arrow button
        buttonLogDown = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/bullet_arrow_down.png")));
        buttonLogDown.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        buttonLogDown.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        buttonLogDown.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                // buttonLogDownActionPerformed(event);
            }
        });
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        add(buttonLogDown, gbc);
    }

    private ImageIcon appendIcons[] = { new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/brick.png")),
            new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/brick_add.png")) };

    /*
    * Event listener methods for the components go here.
    */
}
```

Furthermore, here's the main `JFrame` class which instantiates the `LogPanel`, albeit uncommented. Included is also a download link for the JAR.

[Link](https://privatepaste.com/5293d3d238)

---

I'm using `JPanel.setMinimumSize()` so I can tame the `JTextArea` without using a `JScrollPane`. *I'm thinking the display inconsistency has to do with this.* If I do use a `JScrollPane`, it messes up the panel layout completely, so I'd rather stay away.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT 1:**

If I change the L&F to the default or the system L&F, I get the same issue my friend did; therefore, it's most likely something to do with Nimbus itself.

---

**EDIT 2:**

> It turns out there are differences in the Nimbus code between JDK6,
>   which I was using, and JDK7. I have since updated and replaced the
>   faulty code with `setPreferredSize()`—it works great now.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (no 3rd party APIs, text in place of the images, short..) as an edit to the question.

Comment: @Andrew It turns out there are differences in the Nimbus code between JDK6, which I was using, and JDK7. I have since updated and replaced the faulty code with `setPreferredSize()`—it works great now.

Comment: you should consider to post your comment as an answer and accept it, this way it's easier to find for others with a similar problem :-)

Comment: BTW: you should never-ever use any of the setXXSize, that's asking for trouble (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi/7229519#7229519)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:

> It turns out there are differences in the Nimbus code between JDK6,
>   which I was using, and JDK7. I have since updated and replaced the
>   faulty code with `setPreferredSize()`—it works great now.